# Get number os each duplicated items on table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting duplicate items of my table doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

It returns each duplicate item. But I would like to show:

"repeat X times".

How can I "echo" the "count" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show the `count()`, instead of `*`:

```
select name, count(*)
from table
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot! 
I'll set this as best answer in 7 minutes (stackoverflow requires this time). Thanks again. 

I set count(*) as count and called $line['count'];